# shared_ptr not being destroyed when use_cout() == 1

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I currently have a `shared_ptr` which has a `use_count()` of 1 because of this I expect the `shared_ptr` to be destroyed automatically (without having to call `reset()`) However this does not happen.

My question is am I missing something here? and are there any scenarios that cause `shared_ptr` not to be destroyed?

Some of my classes are GUI classes which dont consist of a constructor or destructor and have a Init() and Shutdown() function. And for this type of class the shared_ptr does not seem to be get destroyed automatically.

Thanks,

Comment: A `shared_ptr` get destroyed when `use_count()` reaches 0 (this is when the only `shared_ptr` left goes out of scope)

Comment: @Xaqq But if the `use_count()` is 1 then when that `shared_ptr` goes out of scope the `use_count()` should be 0 which should then call the destructor and so on right...

Comment: What about a code snippet so we may spot any subtlety?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell Yes that's exactly what should happen.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the obvious: if the `shared_ptr` has a count of 1, it means there is still one reference on it.
Actually, if you can access this reference count, it means you are using a `shared_ptr` on the object. Thus, the count of 1 is natural in this case.

The following will happen: if you are using a local `shared_ptr` in a function, then the `shared_ptr` object will be destroyed when the function reaches its end. As a consequence, this pointer being the last on the object, the pointed object will be destroyed when the function ends.

However, if the pointer is stored in a persistent way (let's say: as a member of an object that exists during the entire life of the program), the reference will always exists, and thus the object will never be destroyed.
A way to work around this would be to periodically check the reference count, and call `reset()` when the reference count is 1.

**BUT**: if you have to do this, there is probably a problem with the way you deal with the `shared_ptr` object: Are you sure this reference is needed? Maybe you should have a `weak_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`? This way, a `weak_ptr` doesn't count as a reference to the object, and it will be destroyed whatever the number of `weak_ptr` targeting it.

Doing this, you can still access the object using the `weak_ptr` while the object exist but, obviously, no more when the object is destroyed. You just ensure the object still exist before accessing it. This is done by using a `lock()` on the `weak_ptr`: it returns a `shared_ptr` to the object, but this pointer can be a `nullptr` if the object doesn't exist any more. Just check if the pointer is a `nullptr` after doing the `lock()`. Alternatively, you can use the `expired()` function to check whether the reference is still valid.